# Do $IJ$ and $I\cap J$ coincide if $I$ and $J$ are coprime? Also if ring $R$ has a $1$ and is not commutative?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring (with identity) and let $I,J$ be two coprime (two-sided) ideals
in it.

In **Algebra: Chapter $0$, Aluffi, III. exercise 4.5.**

the reader is asked to prove that:

> $$IJ=I\cap J$$

I have the following proof for $IJ+JI=I\cap J$:

It is evident that $IJ+JI\subset I\cap J$, and if $i+j=1$ with $i\in I$ and $j\in J$ then for $a\in I\cap J$
we have: $a=ia+ja\in IJ+JI$.

So I would be ready if $R$ is commutative, but that is **not** one of the
data.

Can you help me with a proof or counterexample?

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: if $R$ is not commutative, then require $I$ and $J$ to be two-sided ideals.

Comment: @lhf $I$ and $J$ *are* indeed two-sided ideals. But how does that help?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222474/assume-r-is-commutative-if-ij-r-prove-that-ij-i-cap-j-provide-a-count?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

I have had a look on [this](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~aluffi/algebraerrata/Errata.html) where errors in the book mentioned in the question are exposed. The ring should be a commutative one after all. In that case $$IJ+JI=IJ$$  so my proof is complete.

I am not really interested in a counterexample when it comes to rings that are not commutative.